# Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 5.0 - AspectJ in Maven

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I am trying to use the `aspectj-maven-plugin` in a maven project. At compile time, I get:

```
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 5.0
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 5.0
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 5.0
```

Yet, I set the following in my pom.xml:

```
<project.build.source>1.6</project.build.source>
<project.build.target>1.6</project.build.target>
```

I have some dependencies to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

How do I solve this issue? Thanks.

**Solution**

I added the following in my pom.xml and now it works:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${project.build.source}</source>  <- Addition
                        <target>${project.build.target}</target>  <- Addition
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Comment: @Paul No I did not. Now it works. If you create a solution, I'll approve it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I needed the addition of the complianceLevel configuration argument as well.  See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548548/adding-aspectj-to-pom-xml-changed-java-version-with-maven-why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can explicity set the source parameter of the aspectj plugin. Docs [here](http://mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source).

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this issue by adding the following to my pom:

```
<properties>
<project.build.java.target>1.6</project.build.java.target>
</properties>
```

was able to find this from [this](http://www.hascode.com/2010/08/spring-3-maven-and-annotation-based-configuration/) post.

Answer (score 4):

Check this [page](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usingReport.html) and I see a "complianceLevel" configuration property in that example; setting that to 1.5 or 1.6 might do the trick (since they have a minimum of 1.4, I'm guessing that's the default).